# How to find a curve which satisfies some properties?

Tags: curves

> Let $C$ be a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ passing through $(3,5)$ and $L(x,y)$ denote the segment of the tangent line to $C$ at $(x,y)$ lying in the first quadrant. Assuming that each point $(x,y)$ of $C$ in the first quadrant is the midpoint of $L(x,y)$, find the curve.

First I found the equation of the line whose line segment in first quadrant is $L(3,5)$, which is $5x+3y=30 \ [\text{ It is easy to find as (3,5) will be mid-point of the line}].$

From here how can we find the equation of the curve?

Any help is appreciated. Thnak you.

Comment: If we initially assume that the curve is some differentiable function $y$ of $x$ defined at all points, then the first sentence implies that this curve  is strictly decreasing. So far I've not found a way to specify the curve further. Are you sure the conditions are sufficient? Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: It's from PhD entrance exam question (2017) of INDIAN STATISTICAL INSTITUTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the curve be parametrized by $c(t) =\big(x(t), y(t)\big)$, where $c(0) = (3,5)$.
The tanget $T_t$ at $c(t)$ is given by the parametrization

\begin{align}
T_t(s)
&=
c(t) + s\cdot \big(x'(t), y'(t)\big)
\\&=
\Big(x(t) + s\cdot x'(t)\,, \,\,\,y(t) + s\cdot y'(t)\Big)
.\end{align}

Notice that near $t=0$, the curve lies on the first quadrant.
Near $t=0$, we may hence not have $x'=0$ or $y'=0$, for then the midpoint condition would be impossible to satisfy.

Then, for $t$ near $0$, $T_t$ crosses the $y$-axis when

$$s_{y, t} =  \frac{-y(t)}{y'(t)},$$

and $T_t$ crosses the $x$-axis when

$$s_{x, t} =  \frac{-x(t)}{x'(t)}.$$

The midpoint between them is $T_t\left(\frac12(s_{y,t} + s_{x,t})\right)$, and we have

\begin{align}
s_{y,t} + s_{x,t}
&=
\frac{-y(t)x'(t) -x(t)y'(t)}{x'(t)y'(t)}
\\
\\&=
-\,\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\big[x(t)y(t)\big]}{x'(t)y'(t)}.
\end{align}

For $t$ near $0$, we need to have

$$T_t\left(\frac12(s_{y,t} + s_{x,t})\right) = c(t),$$

which simplifies to

$$(s_{y,t} + s_{x,t}) \cdot \Big(x'(t), y'(t)\Big) = 0.$$

Since neither $x'$ nor $y'$ may be $0$, it follows that for $t$ near $0$ we must have

$$s_{y,t} + s_{x,t} = 0 \iff \frac{d}{dt}\big[x(t)y(t)\big] = 0
\iff x(t)y(t) \,\text{ is constant}$$

Substituting $t=0$ we get $x(0)y(0) = 15$, so the curve looks like

$$y = \frac{15}x,$$

at least in its domain of definition in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

The segment L, by definition, must cut the axes at points $(2x, 0)$ and $(0,2y)$ and the tangent at $(x, y)$ is given by the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{ 2y}{-2x}$ whose solution is $y=\dfrac cx$. The constant $c$ is clearly $ 15$ so the curve $C$ has equation
$$xy=15$$  which is an equilateral hyperbola, symmetric with respect to the diagonal $y = x$ in which it is easy to verify that the tangential segment $L$ corresponding to the arbitrary point $(x, y)$ of the curve $C$ has extremes $(2x, 0)$ and $(0,2y)$.   This curve, in turn, it is well defined on the third quadrant.